# Android help with ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I draw an ImageView from the OnDraw() method? canvas.() does not have to call a resource?

I am trying to do this

```
        @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        imageBack = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);    
        canvas.drawBitmap(imageBack, (x /2)-15 ,y /2, null); 
        //touchEvents();
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);



    }
```

Comment: Add more details so that you can get the specifics you're looking for in answer :)

Comment: See above, I am trying to draw the ImageView.. but i dont know how to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have improved you onDraw method plz check

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    imageBack = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);    
    imageBack.setBounds(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    imageBack.draw(canvas);

}
```

you are not very much clear. so if you find any diffuculty you can add comment to my post

Comment: Thank you Sunil, and how would I be able to add an image view from OnDraw in my view?

Comment: i am not getting. plz be specific to you problem